# docker -v binding local directory to /home/user folder

Tags: docker

Hi I'm trying to bind nginx /usr/share/nginx/html directory to my linux home directory is this the right command to do it?

```
user@localhost ~: pwd
/home/user


sudo docker container run -d -p 8080:80 -v "$(pwd)":/usr/shares/nginx/html --name nginx-website nginx
```

But when I try to ls index.html is not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed the right command to mount your current directory (`/home/user` here) to `/usr/shares/nginx/html`. But be careful, you have probably made a mistake and wanted to use `/usr/share/nginx/html` (`share` folder instead of `shares`).

Anyway, assuming this mistake is fixed, and if you have a `/home/user/index.html` on your host, `docker exec nginx ls index.html` shows nothing because the working directory of `nginx` container is `/`. Therefore, since `ls index.html` is issued from `/`, and there is no `/index.html`, you don't see anything.

You have 2 solutions to see your `index.html` :

- change working directory : `docker exec -w /usr/share/nginx/html nginx ls index.html`
- access `index.html` via its absolute path : `docker exec nginx ls /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`